# Сохранение многие ко многим laravel

Tags: php, laravel

У меня имеется три собой таблицы:

```
items (товары) - id, name
items_categories - id, item_id, category_id
categories (категории) - id, title
```

Как они связаны думаю понятно. Товар может иметь несколько категорий. Вывести в таблицу товары и категории к ним у меня получилось. Теперь пытаюсь сделать возможным добавление нового товара и выбор категорий к нему. Читаю в разных источниках везде как-то по-разному делается.

Items.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Items extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['name'];

    public function category() {
      return $this->belongsToMany('App\Categories', 'category_items','item_id','category_id');
    }
}
```

ItemsController.php

```
class ItemsController extends Controller
{
  public function index() {

    $item = new Items();
    $items = $item->with('category')->get();

    return view('items.index', [
      'items' => $items,
    ]);
  }
  public function store(Request $request) {

        $rules = [
            'name' => 'required|min:3|max:255',
        ];
        $messages = [
            'required' => 'Введите название категории!'
        ];
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules, $messages);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return Redirect::to('items/create')
                ->withErrors($validator);
        } else {

            $items = new Items;
            $items->fill($request->all());
            $items->save();

            Session::flash('message', 'Товар успешно создана');
            return Redirect::to('items');
        }

  }
  public function create() {

    $categories = Categories::get();

    return view('items.create', [
      'categories' => $categories,
    ]);
  }

  public function update(Request $request, $id) {

    $rules = [
      'name' => 'unique:items|min:3|max:255'
    ];
    $messages = [
      'unique' => 'Такой Товар уже имеется!'
    ];
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(),$rules, $messages);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
            return Redirect::to('items/' . $id . '/edit')
                ->withErrors($validator);
    } else {
            $item = supermegalaravel\Items::find($id);
            $item->fill($request->all());
            $item->save();

            Session::flash('message', 'Товар успешно отредактирован!');
            return Redirect::to('items');
    }
  }

  public function destroy($id) {
    $item = Items::find($id);
    $item->delete();
    Session::flash('message', 'Товар успешно удален');
    return Redirect::to('items');
  }

  public function edit($id) {
    $item = Items::find($id);

    return view('items.edit', [
        'item' => $item,
    ]);
  }
}
```

create.blade.php

```
    {{ Form::open(['url' => 'items']) }}

        <div class="form-group">
            {{ Form::label('name', 'Название товара') }}
            {{ Form::text('name', Input::old('name'), ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
            {{ Form::label('categories', 'Категории') }}

            <select class="form-control" name="categories" multiple="multiple">
              @foreach ($categories as $category)
                <option value="{{ $category->title }}">{{ $category->title }}</option>
              @endforeach
            </select>

        </div>

        {{ Form::submit('Создать товар', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) }}

    {{ Form::close() }}
```

index.blade.php

```
 <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
      <tr>
        <th>Название товара</th>
        <th>Категории</th>
        <th>Действия</th>
      </tr>
      @foreach($items as $item)
      <tr>
        <td class="col-md-8">{{ $item->name }}</td>
        <td>
          <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
            @foreach ($item->category as $category)
            <tr>
              <td>
                {{ $category->title }}
              </td>
            </tr>
            @endforeach
          </table>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified">
            <div class="btn-group">
              <a class="btn btn-small btn-info" href="{{ route('items.edit', $item->id) }}">Редактировать</a>

              {!! Form::open(['method' => 'DELETE', 'route' => ['items.destroy', $item->id]]) !!}
                <button class="btn btn-small btn-danger" onclick="return confirm('Вы уверены?');" >Удалить</button>
              {!! Form::close() !!}
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      @endforeach
  </table>
```

Comment: в  чем проблема то?

Comment: Не получается сделать добавление товара с категориями через select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В create.blade.php в качестве значений элементов `option` используйте `$category->id`

```
{{ Form::open(['url' => 'items']) }}

    <div class="form-group">
        {{ Form::label('name', 'Название товара') }}
        {{ Form::text('name', Input::old('name'), ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
        {{ Form::label('categories', 'Категории') }}

        <select class="form-control" name="categories" multiple="multiple">
          @foreach ($categories as $category)
            <option value="{{ $category->id }}">{{ $category->title }}</option>
          @endforeach
        </select>

    </div>

    {{ Form::submit('Создать товар', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) }}

{{ Form::close() }}
```

В методах `store` и `update`, вместо:

```
$items->fill($request->all());
$items->save();
```

Необходимо сделать так:

```
$items->fill($request->except('categories'));
$items->save();
$items->category()->sync($request->categories);
```

**Замечания:** Метод `sync` удалит все связи с категориями, которых нет в `$request->category_id` если этого не должно быть, необходимо использовать `syncWithoutDetaching` метод.